# overriding ctype<wchar_t>

Tags: c++, unicode, iostream, facet

I'm writing a lambda calculus interpreter for fun and practice. I got iostreams to properly tokenize identifiers by adding a `ctype` facet which defines punctuation as whitespace:

```
struct token_ctype : ctype<char> {
 mask t[ table_size ];
 token_ctype()
 : ctype<char>( t ) {
  for ( size_t tx = 0; tx < table_size; ++ tx ) {
   t[tx] = isalnum( tx )? alnum : space;
  }
 }
};
```

(`classic_table()` would probably be cleaner but that doesn't work on OS X!)

And then swap the facet in when I hit an identifier:

```
locale token_loc( in.getloc(), new token_ctype );
…
locale const &oldloc = in.imbue( token_loc );
in.unget() >> token;
in.imbue( oldloc );
```

There seems to be surprisingly little lambda calculus code on the Web. Most of what I've found so far is full of unicode  `λ` characters. So I thought to try adding Unicode support.

But `ctype<wchar_t>` works completely differently from `ctype<char>`. There is no master table; there are four methods `do_is` x2, `do_scan_is`, and `do_scan_not`. So I did this:

```
struct token_ctype : ctype< wchar_t > {
 typedef ctype<wchar_t> base;

 bool do_is( mask m, char_type c ) const {
  return base::do_is(m,c)
  || (m&space) && ( base::do_is(punct,c) || c == L'λ' );
 }

 const char_type* do_is
  (const char_type* lo, const char_type* hi, mask* vec) const {
  base::do_is(lo,hi,vec);
  for ( mask *vp = vec; lo != hi; ++ vp, ++ lo ) {
   if ( *vp & punct || *lo == L'λ' ) *vp |= space;
  }
  return hi;
 }

 const char_type *do_scan_is
  (mask m, const char_type* lo, const char_type* hi) const {
  if ( m & space ) m |= punct;
  hi = do_scan_is(m,lo,hi);
  if ( m & space ) hi = find( lo, hi, L'λ' );
  return hi;
 }

 const char_type *do_scan_not
  (mask m, const char_type* lo, const char_type* hi) const {
  if ( m & space ) {
   m |= punct;
   while ( * ( lo = base::do_scan_not(m,lo,hi) ) == L'λ' && lo != hi )
    ++ lo;
   return lo;
  }
  return base::do_scan_not(m,lo,hi);
 }
};
```

(Apologies for the flat formatting; the preview converted the tabs differently.)

The code is WAY less elegant. I does better express the notion that only punctuation is additional whitespace, but that would've been fine in the original had I had `classic_table`.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Do I really need all those overloads? (Testing showed `do_scan_not` is extraneous here, but I'm thinking more broadly.) Am I abusing facets in the first place? Is the above even correct? Would it be better style to implement less logic?

Comment: In terms of example code, you might want to look at Scheme or LISP, as both of these languages are based in lambda calculus. There should be some LISP or Scheme code that you can play with.

Comment: All the standard functional languages are nice, but I was hoping to find some cut-and-dried sources of the form `(\foo bar. foo foo \baz.…` ad nauseam. I'd like to play with binary lambda calculus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_lambda_calculus, http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/cl/cl.html) rather than spend time writing esoteric code. But this question is about iostreams and disparity of elegance between wide and narrow characters.

Comment: You're what? you're abusing facets to build a tokenizing parser. I fully expect it too be both brittle and slow. Then again, it is probably _the_ most direct way to learn the ins and outs of iostreams. Thanks for showing us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It's been a year with no substantive answer, and I've learned a lot about iostreams in the meantime…)

The custom facet exists exclusively to serve the string extraction operator `in >> token`. That operator is defined in terms of `use_facet< ctype< wchar_t > >( in.getloc() ).is( ios::space, c )` "for the next available input character *c*." (§21.3.7.9) `ctype::is` is simply a stub for `ctype::do_is`, so it would seem that `do_is` is sufficient.

Nevertheless, recent versions of the GCC standard library do implement `operator>>` in terms of `scan_is`. The catch is that `do_scan_is` is then implemented as a series of calls to `do_is`, virtual dispatch and all. The header file describes `do_scan_is` as a hook for user optimization.

So, it would seem that the as-if rule shelters an implementation that only provides the first override.

Note that the second override, which retrieves mask values, is an odd one out. It could be implemented in terms of the first, by inefficiently building the mask bit by bit. In GCC it is implemented in terms of system calls, inefficently building the mask bit by bit with 15 calls per character. This seems to sacrifice both performance and compatibility. Fortunately it seems nobody uses it.

---

Anyway, this is all well and good, but simply writing a tokenizer using `streambuf_iterator<wchar_t>` is easier, far more extensible, and simplifies exception handling.

Comment: Hah. You answered your own question. Didn't notice it was an older one. Highly informative stuff this.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the code you posted is fine. You could implement some of the methods using others if you wanted simpler code (maybe at the expense of efficiency), but the way you did it is OK.

The disparity is based on the fact that people don't want to have several megabyte tables in their UNICODE programs.